# PHP code to display WP author and not logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, badge

I've been modifying a long abandoned plugin project that provides a Stackoverflow inspired badge system for Wordpress. I have upgraded its code so it functions with the new Wordpress version.

You can view the entire code here if interested: http://pastebin.com/kCWWLPL2

I want to add a code to the author.php page to list the author's awarded badges. So far, I have only managed to display the logged in user's badges with this working code:

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id != 0) {
  rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID' => $user_id));
}
?>
```

I was told to use this code to display the author's badges:

```
<?php
$author = get_user_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'author_name' ) ); 
if ($author->ID > 0) {
  rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID' => $author->ID));
}
?>
```

But it does not return anything on the page. Why? What am I doing wrong here? How can I alter the working get_current_user_id code example so that it will **display the author's badges and not the logged in user's one**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this before the Loop on the author.php page.

```
<?php
$curauth = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author));
rhb_list_badges(array('user_ID'=>$curauth->ID));
?>
```

Taken from the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates).

Comment: I just gave this code a try, it seems to work inside the loop as well.

Comment: Great, glad that works for you. The codex page has other samples if you run into problems.